# jQuery - Utility Vs QuerySelection - methods

Tags: javascript, jquery

> ## Utility methods
>
> **`> Object.getOwnPropertyNames(jQuery).toString();`**
>                       *`"prototype,fn,extend,expando,isReady,error,noop,isFunction,isArray,isWindow,isNumeric,isEmptyObject,isPlainObject,type,globalEval,camelCase,nodeName,each,trim,makeArray,inArray,merge,grep,map,guid,proxy,now,support,find,expr,unique,text,isXMLDoc,contains,filter,dir,sibling,Callbacks,Deferred,when,readyWait,holdReady,ready,acceptData,cache,noData,hasData,data,removeData,_data,_removeData,queue,dequeue,_queueHooks,access,event,removeEvent,Event,clone,buildFragment,cleanData,swap,cssHooks,cssNumber,cssProps,style,css,Tween,easing,fx,Animation,speed,timers,valHooks,attr,removeAttr,attrHooks,propFix,prop,propHooks,parseJSON,parseXML,active,lastModified,etag,ajaxSettings,ajaxSetup,ajaxPrefilter,ajaxTransport,ajax,getJSON,getScript,get,post,_evalUrl,param,parseHTML,offset,noConflict,length,name"`*
>
> ## Query selection methods
>
> **`> Object.getOwnPropertyNames(jQuery.prototype).toString();`**
>                       *`"jquery,constructor,selector,length,toArray,get,pushStack,each,map,slice,first,last,eq,end,push,sort,splice,extend,find,filter,not,is,init,has,closest,index,add,addBack,parent,parents,parentsUntil,next,prev,nextAll,prevAll,nextUntil,prevUntil,siblings,children,contents,ready,data,removeData,queue,dequeue,clearQueue,promise,on,one,off,trigger,triggerHandler,text,append,prepend,before,after,remove,empty,clone,html,replaceWith,detach,domManip,appendTo,prependTo,insertBefore,insertAfter,replaceAll,css,show,hide,toggle,fadeTo,animate,stop,finish,slideDown,slideUp,slideToggle,fadeIn,fadeOut,fadeToggle,delay,val,attr,removeAttr,prop,removeProp,addClass,removeClass,toggleClass,hasClass,blur,focus,focusin,focusout,load,resize,scroll,unload,click,dblclick,mousedown,mouseup,mousemove,mouseover,mouseout,mouseenter,mouseleave,change,select,submit,keydown,keypress,keyup,error,contextmenu,hover,bind,unbind,delegate,undelegate,wrapAll,wrapInner,wrap,unwrap,serialize,serializeArray,ajaxStart,ajaxStop,ajaxComplete,ajaxError,ajaxSuccess,ajaxSend,offset,position,offsetParent,scrollLeft,scrollTop,innerHeight,height,outerHeight,innerWidth,width,outerWidth,size,andSelf"`*
>
> ---

From the [documentation](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/dollar-object-vs-function/), I learnt that,

> - Methods called on jQuery selections are in the `$.fn` namespace, and automatically receive and return the selection as `this`.
> - Methods in the `$` namespace are generally utility-type methods, and do not work with selections; they are not automatically passed any arguments, and their return value will vary.
>
> ---

From the above statement, I infer that,

1) Methods applied on query selections[ex- `jQuery('ul li')`] come from `jQuery.prototype`.

2) Methods coming from `jQuery` are utility methods.

Is my understanding correct?

*Note: beginner*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct.

`jQuery.fn` is a reference to `jQuery.prototype`. When you define a function using `jQuery.fn.myFunction = function() { }`, you can access it using `jQuery("div").myFunction()`. Within this function, you can access the selected elements using `this`, so you can for example run `this.html("newcontent")`, which would in this example equal `jQuery("div").html("newcontent")`.

When you define a function using `jQuery.myFunction = function() { }`, the function will not receive any selected elements, so it is only useful if you pass it some parameters.

Comment: Amidst building applications using jQuery library, How often does a developer require to add a new method/function in `jQuery.prototype` and `jQuery`?

Comment: That question cannot be answered generally. Personally, I’ve rarely had to add more than one or two functions myself. And many times, there is a jquery plugin that does that job that you want to do (which will itself create such functions).